# How to add bootstrap to a PHP code?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to style a PHP website using bootstrap. Most of the website including things like textbox and select are coded in PHP. How do I add bootstrap to it?

```
 array("type"=>"select", "name"=>"agentId", "value"=>getAgentASMOption($partyCode), "title"=>"Select Party");
```

Comment: can you add class or id?

Comment: How are you building your html tags from this array?

Comment: I don't know. I've been given a currently existing project by the company. And I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap framework is just a library with classes and id's for styling HTML elements.

You can add the required class name in your php array in below manner.

```
array("type"=>"select", "class"=>"yourclass" , "name"=>"agentId", "value"=>getAgentASMOption($partyCode), "title"=>"Select Party");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class attribute as :

```
array("type"=>"select", "name"=>"agentId", "value"=>getAgentASMOption($partyCode), "title"=>"Select Party","class"=>"myclass");
```

and then in css

```
.myclass{
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class attribute in your array and css to that class.

```
array("type"=>"select", "name"=>"agentId", "value"=>getAgentASMOption($partyCode), "title"=>"Select Party", "class"=>"selectClass");
```

css

```
.selectClass{
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console whether it is giving any error

Comment: No errors mate. It's just giving the same output. A simple dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is nothing more than a CSS and JS. You just need to add class/ID in HTML elements. I am assuming that in your PHP code have capabilities to add these things using array keys and values.

```
 array("type"=>"select", "name"=>"agentId", "value"=>getAgentASMOption($partyCode), "id"=>"fieldID", "class"=>"cssClass", "title"=>"Select Party");
```

Now you need to define these class in your css files. Make sure you define different values for responsive purpose in media query.

Comment: does it add ID and class element in your HTML tag?

Comment: I traced this array to another php file where the code is written in a function named getAgentASMOption like this:
$str .= '<option value="'.$asm['partyCode'].'" '.$sel.'>'.$asm['NAME1'].' ----- '.$asm['ORT01'].' -----  '.$asm['partyCode'].' </option>';

Comment: it means it doesnt adding remain stuff... add pure HTML tag instead of php line to generate HTML and than you will be free to do anything with it.